# How to redirect a wget output to a newly created directory

Tags: linux, terminal

So I want to write a shell script which first creates a folder based on the year and month.
Then it is followed by a wget command which downloads a file.

```
mkdir $(date + "%Y%b") #create a new directory
wget https:www.testweb.com/file=312
```

How do i make sure that the wget command **outputs the file downloaded** to the **newly created directory** in the first line?

Comment: Use the `-P` option.

Comment: Or you could simply cd to the directory.

Comment: BTW, you forgot `//` before the server name.